# SQL Query multi reference to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables Task and User

```
Task       PRIMARY KEY
IdTask  
TaskName
IdHandler  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES IdUser
IdCreator  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES IdUser
```

```
User
IdUser     PRIMARY KEY
Name
```

How to query with IdHandler and IdCreator reference to IdUser

Expected Result: TaskName, Name(Handler), Name(Creator)

PS: I'm also do not know if I can put Foreign Keys like that, at least SQL Server let me do it.

Comment: SO is about helping you to solve the problem, which means you need to have a go first and then when you are stuck ask a question.

Comment: Are database tables TASK and USER related? Does one table have a foreign key to the other? If there is a foreign key, then [edit] your question and add the details of the foreign key relation between the two tables.

Comment: I've tried for 5 hours i think, but nothing make scene
I dont have any resolution to go first

Comment: @Abra ok im doing it

Comment: @Abra i edited, is it ok now? Sorry for my first question

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TaskName, h.Name [HandlerName], c.Name [CreatorName]
FROM Task t
INNER JOIN User h ON t.IdHandler = h.IdUser
INNER JOIN User c ON t.IdCreator = c.IdUser
```

Comment: accept this as answer. so, it is helpful for others in future.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below query.

```
Select  
    tt.TaskName, 
    userHandler.Name as 'UserHandler',
    userCreator.Name as 'UserCreator'
from 
    TasKTable tt
left join
    User userHandler on userHandler.IdUser = tt.IdHandler
left join
    User userCreator on userCreator.IdCreator = tt.IdHandler
```

select all field from all table

```
 Select 
      tt.*,
      userHandler.*,
      userCreator.*
   from 
      TasKTable tt left join
      User userHandler on userHandler.IdUser = tt.IdHandler left join
      User userCreator on userCreator .IdCreator = tt.IdHandler
```

You may also check this [SQL Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative query not using JOINs

```sql
select T.NAME_TASK
      ,(select U1.NAME from USERS U1 where U1.ID_USER = T.ID_HANDLER) as HANDLER
      ,(select U2.NAME from USERS U2 where U2.ID_USER = T.ID_CREATOR) as CREATOR
  from TASKS T
```

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9ec2ccefcf2dca47b6934554343c50d8)